# Adding Wait Message in my Amazon ALexa skill

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa service which connects to an external service. In order to get the response, it takes around 9-10 seconds. Is there a way to add a message in Alexa while Lambda function is processing the request. Something like - "hang on a second. I am retrieving the results"

Answer (score 4):

You could get Alexa to say that, but then the user would have to say something to your skill for control to return to you.

The only way I can think of to do what you want is to use the audio player to stream a response to the user, so you can be formulating the end of the response while the user is listening to the beginning of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, It is possible through [Progressive Response Api](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html) which targets exactly your use case.

According to docs:

> Your skill can send progressive responses to keep the user engaged
>   while your skill prepares a full response to the user's request. A
>   progressive response is interstitial SSML content (including
>   text-to-speech and short audio) that Alexa plays while waiting for
>   your full skill response.