# Is there a way to handle a long duration request/response for Alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Lets say I have an action for an intent that could take 45 to 90 seconds to complete. I want Alexa to say the request is accepted, and then when the response comes back, to tell the user the result. Is there a way to do this, or does it have to be synchronous and the handler blocks and hope it doesn't time out?

I'm using Amazon Lambda written in Javascript.

Comment: See this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757814/adding-wait-message-in-my-amazon-alexa-skill/45760139#45760139

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Wait Message in my Amazon ALexa skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757814/adding-wait-message-in-my-amazon-alexa-skill)

Comment: As mentioned in the question linked by Tom, this is currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, extending the session timeout duration is not a supported feature of Alexa Skills Kit. There is unfortunately no recommended workaround for latency issues, as response times exceeding 8 seconds aren't supported.

Your skill can send progressive responses to keep the user engaged while your skill prepares a full response to the user's request, more information can be found here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html

I hope this helps.